# MongoDB : How to exclude a collection from generating oplog

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-oplog

I am working on processing the mongodb oplog and I create a collection in mongodb to add the processed data and I don't want this collection to again generate oplog.

I want all other collection to generate oplog but need to exclude one of the collection. How can I achieve this. Is there any settings to let mongodb know not to generate oplog for a collection.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Collection in local database are not part of replication. So, If you create a collection in  the local database and insert records to that, oplog entries are not created.